# How to remove default wordpress header for admin?

Tags: wordpress

[image]

How to remove this from front- end?

Comment: do you want to remove the adminbar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the action hook to remove the adminbar from the front-end

Add below code in your theme functions.php file.

```
 add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_adminbar');

function remove_adminbar() {
if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
  show_admin_bar(false);
 }
}
```

This will show the admin bar only for wordpress admins and
Disable WordPress Admin Bar for all other users

If you want to remove the adminbar for all users then use below code in your functions.php

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Answer (score 1):

throw this in your functions.php

```
/**
* Remove admin bar on homepage.
* 
*/
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

done and done.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code on your function.php,

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```